# PAGE_ID/insights/page_fans/lifetime?until=DATE gives OAuthException for some dates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For some of my fanpages, it gives OAuth error , once you try to get data using /PAGE_ID/insights/page_fans/lifetime Facebook API.

What excatly happened was, I used PAGE_ID/insights/page_fans/lifetime?until=2013-05-04. It pulling through data. But if I use PAGE_ID/insights/page_fans/lifetime?until=2013-05-03 , that means same query a day before the first query, it gives

{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}

Does any have proper explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use date range in /insights/page_fans/lifetime
query it without any parameters

you can combine

```
/insights/page_fans/lifetime
/insights/page_fan_removes
/insights/page_fan_adds
```

to get a daily reading